# JavaScript variable finding solution

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function longest(string) {
        var str = string.split(" ");
        var longest = 0;
        var word = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            document.write(longest);
            if (longest < str[i].length) {
                longest = str[i].length;   
                word = str[i];
            }
        }
        return word;
    }

document.write (longest("Web Development Tutorial"));
```

I'm newbie it is the code for identifying largest word in a string I found this code on Stack Overflow and its working fine but I can not understand the working of var longest that how it is used for comparing the value in if statement because what I think is that it has the value of 0 and nothing else is added into it so how it is working.

Comment: It's getting set whenever longest is shorter than the word in `str[i]`. Analyse the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what is happening

at first

```
longest = 0
```

then

```
longest = 3 (for 'web')
```

then it is comparing

```
longest < 11 (for 'development') true
```

```
longest = 11;
```

next condition becomes false

so it is returning the `word`

Comment: but no value is passed to longest for comparing so how it is getting that value on its own.

Comment: here value is getting assigned longest = str[i].length; for a specific string.

Answer (score 0):

```
longest = str[i].length;
```

This line sets a new value into the longest variable. Then with each iteration of the for loop the new value is used to compare whether the word is longer then the current longest.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the explanation below.

```js
function longest(string) {
        var str = string.split(" "); // Gives an array of words
        var longest = 0; // initializing length of longest word to 0
        var word = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { // loops over the array of words
            document.write(longest);
            // comparing length of each with longest value. If longest is less than the current word length, change the longest word & length
            if (longest < str[i].length) { 
                // setting the length of the word as longest. Here is the longest variable getting updated
                longest = str[i].length;
                document.write(longest);   
                word = str[i]; // setting the longest word
            }
        }
        return word; // returning the longest word set in the above iterator
    }

document.write (longest("Web Development Tutorial"));
```

Additionally, you can simplify the logic to as below using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function longest(string) {
  // Compare length of each word and return the longest word
  return string.split(" ").reduce((a, c) => a.length > c.length ? a : c);
}

document.write(longest("Web Development Tutorial"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-find-largest-element-array/

```js
function longest(string) {
        var str = string.split(" ");
        // let 'longest' word having 0 character and let 'word' is null for starting point
        var longest = 0;
        var word = null;
        // go through all words
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            console.log(longest);
            // if current 'word' is having more number of characters then our 'longest' count
            // then set longest count to current word's length 
            // And set word to current word
            if (longest < str[i].length) {
                longest = str[i].length;
                 console.log(longest);   
                word = str[i];
            }
        }
        // as we go through all words then 'longest' will have longest count and 'word' will have cursponding word and return that longest 'word'.
        return word;
    }

 console.log (longest("Web Development Tutorial"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer looks easy and intuitive. It also has a **demo** you can have a quick look and playground with it.

[Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521571/5391427)

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log("A Web Development Tutorial and VeryLongWoooooord".split(' ').sort((prevWord, nextWord) => {
  if(prevWord.length > nextWord.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  if(prevWord.length === nextWord.length) {
    return 0;
  }
  if(prevWord.length > nextWord.length) {
    return 1;
  }
 })[0]);
```